# unidentified javascript function

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I've been handed a role administering a SharePoint site, and the following custom code is on one of the pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#pgtitle").html("Customer Service Feedback");
       });

</script
```

I'm not a javascript guy, so I'm having trouble interpreting this.  The code was written by someone who is no longer with my firm, and left well before I arrived.

Comment: It uses the JavaScript framework called JQuery to insert the text in quotes to an HTML object on the page. That's all

Comment: saying you are not the javascript guy is a very bad excuse, just going to google and checking javascript basics would have given you a lot of resources

Comment: ok, bad excuses aside, reading through the javascript docs for 3 lines of code seemed excessive.  Also, entering the #pgtitle tag in google turned ugly, so i thought i'd come here for help.  Next time, when i'm not in as much of a rush, i'll dig deeper

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function()` means that the code that follows, will start as soon as the page has loaded.

`$("#pgtitle").html("Customer Service Feedback");` simply passes the value `Customer Service Feedback` to the HTML element `pgtitle`.

if you look on the page for the `pgtitle` element, I'm sure you will see it contains the text `Customer Service Feedback` ! :)

Answer (score 2):

It sets text on the element of id = pgtitle as soon as the DOM document had fully loaded. In human language it manually sets the value of some title.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the JQuery library for the "html" method and if you look for the id that is called "pgtitle" you will find the html that is effected.

Source:http://api.jquery.com/html/